# What if my (duplicate) question is seemingly much better worded than the origin?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

My question marked as duplicated, the link to duplicate is correct, but the existing question is worded with too much detail to unrelevant issues. What to do in such case? I am happy with the answer, but

1. I was not able to find it myself because it is so ambiguously worded.
2. Even reading it is difficult because so much unnecessary information.

So this is not good for the community. I thought that maybe the best solution to edit the original (old, nonduplicate, or whatever you call them) question.

I edited tags and the title. But in fact I should have just replace the whole body of the question and put my own instead because it is so much cleaner and shorter. But the problem is I hesitate to do that. Maybe because I never did anything like that before. Anyway what you suggest be my way of action in such situation?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345995/how-to-show-progress-of-http-geturl

Comment: That question is not difficult to read. It's two short paragraphs. The author gives details about what they're trying to do and is very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are major readability issues with the other question, then you can edit it to correct those. However, since that's not the case, I'd say just leave it as is. The main point of duplicates is for them to act as sign posts, allowing a greater number of different search terms to find questions that will lead back to an answer.

Once your question has been closed as a duplicate, people who find that original question when searching will get the answer **and** those who find your question instead will also get the same answer.